# Better preverifiers than Sun WTK

Tags: java, java-me, preverify

I'm currently using the sun preverifier to preverify my MIDlet. I'm finding that it can be a bit slow, doesnt give any decent error messages and is only available as a windows exe.

Are there any better preverifiers around that will work cross platform (linux specifically)

Answer (score 1):

Proguard can preverify jar files. I guess you could disable the obfuscation if you didn't want that and just preverify with it.

It's a java application so it should run on Linux too.

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#microedition

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is also a linux version of WTK (from Sun) and I am using it every day on Ubuntu. Can't really comment on the speed.

About `Proguard` preverification - for some reasons this does not work, for me, on some jars and I have not been able to figure out why. Running 'preverified' jar with WTK emulator throws preverification errors.